# React Native access this.prop from inside function

Tags: react-native

I have the following code:

```
module.exports = class Menu extends Component {

    about() {
        this.props.nav.push({
            component: TestView,
            title: 'Test View',
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ScrollView
                scrollsToTop={false}
                style={styles.menu}
                navigator={this.props.nav}>
                <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
                    <Image
                        style={styles.logo}
                        source={{ uri, }}/>
                </View>

                <Text onPress={this.about} style={styles.item}>About</Text>
                <Text style={styles.item}>Account</Text>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }
};
```

I keep getting the error message:

```
"undefined is not an object ("evaluating this.props.nav")
```

when "onPress" calls "this.about". I placed a console.log within the render function and I could see that this.props.nav contained a value. The issue occurs in the about() function and I am not sure why.

Any suggestions would be great?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I can't be certain, but this looks like a Javascript `this` binding problem to me.  In ReactJS components defined with the ES6 class syntax do [not automatically bind](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#no-autobinding) `this`, so you're being bitten by Javascript's [rules that vary the value of `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) depending on how a function is called.

You may need to explicitly use `.bind` when setting your button handler:

```
<Text onPress={this.about.bind(this)} style={styles.item}>About</Text>
```

So that `this` in the `about()` function will be the same as the `this` in the `render()` function where you set up the handler.

I found [a repo](https://github.com/annamalai-saro/AutoBinding-in-React) which shows other methods of solving the same problem, like binding in a constructor or using ["Fat-arrow" functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) for your handler.

My experience is with using React for web, and I'm not sure if React Native differs in this area.

Answer (score 6):

You can also re-bind the method declaration itself so that you don't need to remember to call `.bind(this)` in your JSX. This is useful if you have many buttons calling the same function.

For example:

```
class Menu extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // Replace instance method with a new 'bound' version
        this.about = this.about.bind(this);
    }

// Elsewhere in JSX you don't need to remember to call .bind(this)
<Text onPress={this.about} style={styles.item}>About</Text>
```